# Enable TLS1.2 on glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: java, glassfish

I want to enable TLS1.2 on glassfish 3.1.2.2 (build 5) with JDK7, I know JDK7 enables TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1 (default) and SSLv3.

I have upgraded the JDK version to JDK7 from JDK6, i'm connecting to glassfish server via SOAPUI client ( SOAPUI enabled TLS1.2 by setting -Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2) to test a webservice application.

Following error is returning from server.

> ERROR:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Server chose TLSv1, but
>   that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.

I'm confused why glassfish doesn't choose the latest TLS version (TLS1.2) for the handshake.

> Also found a glassfish blog
>   (https://java.net/projects/glassfish/lists/users/archive/2012-07/message/85)
>   stating glassfish3.1.2 had issues running TLS1.2 with JDK1.7

Does anyone successfully connected to glassfish3 via TLS1.2?

Comment: [Perhaps this answer will help.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63481557/6093901)