# TSL 1.2 issue with Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: java, glassfish-3, tls1.2

I am trying to update TSL to 1.2 on glassfish v3.1.2.2 server, and I have tried for days I got no luck.
when I put below configuration to glassfish

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
or
 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

I got following error:

```
Severe: PWC3989: An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.CsrfProtectionFilter.handle(CsrfProtectionFilter.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter.handle(HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java:81)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:563)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.security.AdminConsoleAuthModule.validateRequest(AdminConsoleAuthModule.java:256)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.jmac.config.GFServerConfigProvider$GFServerAuthContext.validateRequest(GFServerConfigProvider.java:1171)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.validate(RealmAdapter.java:1452)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1330)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHello(ClientHandshaker.java:449)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:203)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:897)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1033)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1342)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1369)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1353)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler$1$1.getOutputStream(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:225)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.commitWrite(CommittingOutputStream.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:89)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.BaseFormProvider.writeTo(BaseFormProvider.java:109)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormMultivaluedMapProvider.writeTo(FormMultivaluedMapProvider.java:99)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormMultivaluedMapProvider.writeTo(FormMultivaluedMapProvider.java:59)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:300)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:204)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
    ... 32 more
```

I have to get the update done, due to the update from the payment gateway company. If this does not work, none of the transaction will go through. please help , thank you

Comment: this problem is tricky. we have 2 version of glassfish v3 deployed in test and prod. Depends on what version you have, the solution is different.  Yes, i have resolved this problem.

Comment: I am using glassfish version 3.1.2.2. It would be great if you can share the solution.

Comment: i wish i could, my solution is at my previous job. now i have no access so i can not give to you. sorry. i could not remember it since it is long time ago and it was tricky. :(

Answer (score 0):

In short:

- this needs Java 8 or Java 7 v1.7.0_131-b31 (which enable by default TLS v1.2 on client sockets) 
   **OR** at least Java 7u95 (on which TLS v1.2 should be enabled on client sockets)
- Then setup Glassfish for using TLS v1.2

See details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523279

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue even while using Java 8. After a bit of debugging, I found that there are some security enhancements done in Java 8 after build 65, which were causing the issue. The server was using TLS v1 while it was disabled into client side.so, I did override the property

```
  Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms","");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using java 8 for this you need to write `jre-1.8 = $ {jre-1.7}` at the bottom of the `osgi.properties` file `.\glassfish3\glassfish\config`.

Then you need to edit `domain.xml` `\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\DOMAIN_NAME\config`
add `tls-enabled = "false" tls11-enabled = "false" tls12-enabled = "true"` to the ssl tag in your http-listener.

[Details about edit domain.xml](https://community.appdynamics.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-to-disable-TLS-1-0-and-TLS-1-1-on-the-AppDynamics-Controller/ta-p/25657)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

- upgraded to Java 8u341
- applied the patch mentioned [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/18949#issuecomment-421899299) by copying the patched `grizzly-config.jar` (from [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/18949#issuecomment-421899303)) into `<GF3_INSTALL>/glassfish/modules/`
- added `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` to the server JVM Options
- restarted the server